# What property is exposed to outside when using const { }

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I follow the example of ngrx store as follows

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiple-entities-in-same-state?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstate%2Freducers%2Fexample.reducer.ts

There is a code in example.reducer.ts

```
export const { selectAll: selectAllCars } = adapterCar.getSelectors();
```

And the outside calls

```
export const selectAllCars = createSelector(selectCarState, fromExample.selectAllCars);
```

Not call `selectAll`

Sorry to ask but I have no idea how to search it. Could you please explain how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a destructuring assignment. It's supposed to improve code readibility, but I wonder if it isn't misused here.

```
export const { selectAll: selectAllCars } = adapterCar.getSelectors();
```

means the same as

```
const carSelectors = adapterCar.getSelectors();
const selectAllCars = carSelectors.selectAll;
export { selectAllCars };
```

Comment: Thank @mbojko so that explanation